# where to find piano symbols dataset

Tags: piano, notation

I want to detect piano symbols from pictures using machine learning.
My issue is that I couldn't find a decent dataset to train my model.

any recommendations ?

Comment: Do you mean just piano sheet music? That's the biggest and most relevant data set for piano notation. If you google "classical piano sheet music" I think you'll get at least one hit with a large public-domain library in PDF format.

Comment: Welcome! What does "piano symbols" mean? Please edit your question to clarify. And if you mean decoding written music, Optical Character Recognition has been doing that for decades (and just about getting competent by now).

Comment: @AndyBonner well I did some research and found out that each musical instrument has its own "language". meaning if I look at a piano music sheet and say a guitar music sheet some symbols don't exist in the other. So I only want to perform machine learning on piano music sheets.

Comment: What is your goal exactly? I mean let's say you teach an AI network to "detect piano symbols" (not sure what you mean with that) then what happens? Does it play the music? Perform a functional analysis? Create a fireworks show?

Comment: The standard symbols (but without context) are given at [Dolmetsch](https://dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm).

Comment: I don't agree with the closing reason given above, but some details concerning acquired knowledge is indispensable. *Pedal symbol detected at x=, y=* surely is useless. If you are searching a decent topic for machine learning I suggest to look elsewhere: there are many irregularities and complexities in musical notation which will cause a very long and steep learning curve.

Comment: @DarkLeader "... each musical instrument has its own 'language'. meaning if I look at a piano music sheet and say a guitar music sheet some symbols don't exist in the other." Oof, that sentence takes some explaining. Unless we're talking about  *tablature*, like for guitar, which is a totally different system of representing pitches and is unique to each instrument, then most instruments use a standard "music notation" system that they share. It *is* true that there are some words or markings that might be unique to a certain instrument, but they're only a small part of the printed data. ...

Comment: @DarkLeader ... If you showed me a piece of sheet music and I had to guess which instrument it's for, there are often some clues, but it would often be impossible. A short bit of piano, organ, or harp music might look the same; some passages for violin or flute could be the same; guitar could be impossible to tell from violin especially if you can't hear the result or see the start of the line. It's not true that each instrument has a "different language"; more like most of them speak the same language and occasionally use some specialized "words."

Comment: @AndyBonner like I said, i'm not trying to classify every single music sheet ever made and break it down to its notes and symbols - I only want to tackle piano music sheets. and thus I only want to find sheets with piano symbols (I don't care if other sheets have some overlap in the symbols used even though they are using a different instrument)

Comment: @DarkLeader What I mean is, the phrase "piano symbols" is a really weird one and we're having a hard time defining it. If it means "the way music for piano is notated," then it gets into the whole field of reading music notation. If you mean the stuff that's unique to piano, like pedal markings, that's another topic. And as others have commented, optical character recognition of music notation has already been developed, and teaching AI to do it all over again could be challenging.

Comment: @AndyBonner can you provide a link to a working optical music recognition github repo? haven't found a single working solution.

Comment: @DarkLeader (And wait, is the question just "where do I find music for piano"? A quick google should provide many sites. IMSLP.org contains thousands of pages of "real," published music that's in the public domain.)

Comment: @DarkLeader As for open-source OCR, I'm not sure about that. I've used it as a plugin in the music notation software Sibelius and Finale.

Comment: Note that different fonts are used and that the sheet music has evolved (only on this site have I seen three different pedal markings). But perhaps an initial set could be generated from open source unicode fonts for music, or just cramming in stuff in sheet music programs and printing. I did find open source ocr software for music but the results were not good enough for me. They did not call it ocr I believe, they used a different acronym.